# Problems with ListView and layout

Tags: android, list, sqlite, listview, view

i'm using android studio and  i'm trying to follow this guide: http://tinyurl.com/oelsg7o that implements database but i have problems with " **R.layout.listactivity_row**.
This guide not explain nowhere  how and where to insert "listactiviry_row"
Can you help me ?

```
@Override
public View newView(Context ctx, Cursor arg1, ViewGroup arg2)
{

         View v=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listactivity_row, null);
         return v;
}
```

this is main_activiry.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="400dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/oggetto"
    android:hint="Oggetto"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="53dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/testo"
    android:hint="testo"
    android:layout_below="@+id/oggetto"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/oggetto"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/oggetto"
    android:layout_marginRight="53dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/data"
    android:hint="data"
    android:layout_below="@+id/testo"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/testo"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/testo" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="salva"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/txt_subject"
        android:hint="subject" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/txt_date"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-16dp"
        android:hint="data" />


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Put any Layout xml file in the `layout`-Folder...

Comment: i have only main_layout.xml and it is in loyout folder!

Answer (score 0):

This is the row file you need, make a new xml file in layout folder as listactivity_row.xml
and copy paste below code in that file

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_delete"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/big_textstyle"
        android:id="@+id/txt_subject"/>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/small_textstyle"
        android:id="@+id/txt_date"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageButton 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
         android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah, works but when i click "salva" not display database items!

Comment: @GentooAntoo     because it is not saving to database anyhow, check the code twice and if my answer helped you, please accept it as correct answer

Comment: @GentooAntoo Put adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); as the last line of if { } block inside salva() method

Comment: i followed your suggestion but still not display anything!

Comment: @GentooAntoo try to print data which is being saved in salve method, check logcat if the data is going to database or not